# I am trying to create an XML and XSL, but it is giving me an error that I can't figure out what to do

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I am trying to create a xml file linked to xsl and whenever I run it, any browser I use says the same error. I have tried researching what to do but I still don't get it. I saw something about security and permission but I tried and still got the same result.

Can anyone please help? I am new with XML working with HTML learning through a book. I could not find anything that will help me and really want to see what I am doing wrong or what the work around will be at this point. Thank you in advance!!

XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="chapter10XML.xsl"?>

    <!DOCTYPE myProducts [
    <!ELEMENT myProducts (product)>
    <!ELEMENT product (prodName, prodImg, description, price, stockLevel, sku)>
    ]>

    <myProducts>
    <product id = "i7-8">
        <prodName>I7 8th Generation</prodName>
        <prodImg>/images.i7-8thgen.jpg</prodImg>
        <description>Core i7-8700K can reach a frequency of 4.7GHz. These chips 
    can be expanded with up to 40 platform PCIe 3.0 lanes.</description>
        <price>$300.00</price>
        <stockLevel>25</stockLevel>
        <sku>INT-78</sku>
    </product>

    <product id = "i5-8">
        <prodName>I5 8th Generation</prodName>
        <prodImg>/images.i5-8thgen.jpg</prodImg>
        <description>Intel Core i5-8400 comes with 6 processing Cores and 6 
    Threads.</description>
        <price>$250.00</price>
        <stockLevel>20</stockLevel>
        <sku>INT-58</sku>
    </product>

    <product id = "i3-8">
        <prodName>I3 8th Generation</prodName>
        <prodImg>/images.i3-8thgen.jpg</prodImg>
        <description>Intel Core i3 comes with 4 processing Cores and 4 Threads. 
   </description>
        <price>$200.00</price>
        <stockLevel>20</stockLevel>
        <sku>INT-38</sku>
    </product>

    <product id = "i5-7">
        <prodName>I5 7th Generation</prodName>
        <prodImg>/images.i5-7thgen.jpg</prodImg>
        <description>64-bit dual-core mid-range performance x86 mobile 
    microprocessor introduced by Intel in mid-2016.</description>
        <price>$170.00</price>
        <stockLevel>20</stockLevel>
        <sku>INT-57</sku>
    </product>

    <product id = "i3-7">
        <prodName>I3 7th Generation</prodName>
        <prodImg>/images.i3-7thgen.jpg</prodImg>
        <description>Core i3-7100U is a 64-bit dual-core low-end performance x86 
    mobile microprocessor introduced by Intel in mid-2016.</description>
        <price>$170.00</price>
        <stockLevel>20</stockLevel>
        <sku>INT-37</sku>
    </product>

    </myProducts>
```

My XSLT so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Chapter 10 XML</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <xsl:for-each select="/chapter10XML/myProducts/product">
            <div class="product">
              <h3>
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
              </h3>
              <p>
                <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
              </p>
              <p>
                <img src="[prodImg]"/>
              </p>
              <p>
                <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
              </p>
              <p>In Stock: <xsl.value-of select="stocklevel"/></p>
              <p>
                <xsl:value-of select="sku"/>
              </p>
            </div>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The error says This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

Comment: Is the XSL file saved in the same directory as the XML file? Also, is the name of the XSL file exactly "chapter10XML.xsl" (i.e you don't have a typo? Or may maybe a case-sensitivity issue?)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you only have to change two things:

- Change the output method in `<xsl:output...` to `<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" ...`
- And change the `<xsl:for-each...` to

  ```
  <xsl:for-each select="/myProducts/product">
  ```

  because the `/chapter10XML` root element is not present in the XML.

Now you get an HTML output that can be rendered in a browser.

---

If you get a security error, you're probably using Chrome as a browser, which has tight restrictions on executing local files.

Comment: Were you able to try it? I applied the changes and still the same result. Also, I am using firefox. Thanks

Comment: I was able to try this using Firefox and it was okay. The XSL file should be in the same directory as the XML file.